# L2 Norm of Expectation

Tags: probability, normed-spaces, expected-value, conditional-expectation

This question may be more suited for the statistics sister site, but I thought I would start here.

I'm posed with proving the following statement:

Let $X,Y$ be random variables on some probability space, and let $Z=E[X\mid Y]$ prove
$$||X||_{L_2}^2 = ||X-Z||_{L_2}^2+||Z||_{L_2}^2$$

I'm immediately a little stuck. How can I take the L2 norm of expectation? Once I figure that out I'm sure this follows from linearity/iterated expectation but I'm not sure how I should be dealing with the expectation inside the norm? Am I missing some way to be arrange it nicely? I am also suspicious that there is some super simple algebra I am missing to show this too.

Any pointers would be appreciated, surely I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I assume the $L^2$ is just there for unambiguity, i.e. $$||X||_{L^2} = \sqrt{\int X^2 dP}$$ as you would expect. Also, $Z = E[X | Y]$ is a random variable, as it depends on the value of the random variable $Y$.

Comment: Yes that is our definition of l2 norm, I just don’t know how to take X-E[X|Y] inside the norm. Like how do I apply the norm to the expectation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, for potential future viewers, I made some progress in realizing the norm ||X||_L2^2 is equal to (E|X|^2)^(2/2). Which seems like the road to go down here, but now stuck with what to do with the exponents, as I can't easily combine the two terms to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big hint: $L^2$ is an inner product space. The inner product is just what you’d expect: $$\langle X, Y \rangle := \int XY dP = \Bbb{E}[XY].$$ So rewrite the LHS as $$||X||^2 = \langle X, X \rangle = \langle (X - Z) + Z, (X - Z) + Z \rangle,$$ and use properties of inner products (*and, of course, conditional/iterated expectations*) to make it look like the RHS.

**Edit:** $Z = \Bbb{E}[X | Y]$ may be an "expectation", but it need not be constant.
Concrete example: I enter a casino with a thousand dollars and stake a hundred dollars on a sequence of three fair bets (i.e. I win or lose a hundred dollars each bet with 50-50 probability).
Let $X$ be my final net worth, and $Y$ be the indicator r.v. of me winning the *first* bet in the sequence (i.e. $Y = 1$ if I win the first bet and $Y = 0$ otherwise). Then it's not hard to show that $$Z = \Bbb{E}[X | Y] = 900 + 200Y,$$ since $$\Bbb{E}[X | Y = 1] = \sum x \Bbb{P}[X = x |Y = 1] = 1100$$ and $$\Bbb{E}[X | Y = 0] = \sum x \Bbb{P}[X = x |Y = 0] = 900.$$ $Z$ is clearly a coarser random variable than $X$, that nonetheless represents $X$ to the greatest degree possible given the limited information afforded by $Y$.

From personal experience, I find that conditional expectation is really hard to understand if your first exposure to it is the super abstract, measure theoretic setting (like when my graduate probability course was working out of Durrett, which has many things to recommend it but is pitched to the level of someone with lots of preexisting familiarity with the basics).
It's probably better to start with conditional expectation for discrete r.v.'s and then look at the continuous case after that. Here are a [couple](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/andreas-klappenecker/csce658-s18/cond_expectation.pdf) [sources](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Efewster/325/notes/ch3.pdf) that do that nicely. I also TA'd for an undergrad probability class that worked out of Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis' book, which I would recommend.
Wikipedia has [a long list of relevant properties of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) as well, and also talks about its interpretation as [the orthogonal projection of $X$ into the subspace of $L^2$ spanned by all measurable functions of $Y$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra) (which is the substance of what this exercise asks you to prove.)

Comment: This is very clean, and much more logical than my proof. I posted mine below as an answer, would you mind taking a look at my method and seeing if it is correct?

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth reply. Your example of expectation was very easy to understand. The course I'm in is a second year graduate course and is actually my first course ever in probability/statistics, so some of the basic understand is completely lost on me. I appreciate you taking the time to list the sources, I have been slowly working through the first link.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at a proof:

\begin{align}
||X-Z||_2^2 + ||Z||_2^2 &= E[(X-Z)^2]+E[Z^2]\\
&=E[X^2-2XZ+Z^2]+E[Z^2]\\
&=E[X^2]-2E[XZ]+2E[Z^2]\\
&=E[X^2]-2ZE[X]+2ZE[Z] \text{ ******}\\
&=E[X^2]-2E[X|Y]E[X]+2E[X|Y]E[E[X|Y]]\\
&=E[X^2]-2E[X|Y]E[X]+2E[X|Y]E[X]\\
&=E[X^2]\\
&=||X||_2^2
\end{align}

The last term in the line with the asterisks is what I am concerned about, am I able to pull one Z out and leave the other (since Z is constant... right)?

Comment: This is substantially equivalent to the inner product approach detailed above. The big issue is exactly the starred step: when $X$ is not independent of $Y$, $Z = \Bbb{E}[X|Y]$ is not a constant, but rather some function of $Y$. So it doesn't even make sense to say, for instance, that $2 \Bbb{E}[XZ]$ (which is a plain number) is equal to $2 Z\Bbb{E}[X]$ (which is a non-constant random variable). I'm going to update my answer with an example of non-constant conditional expectation, and some links to/recommendations of sources.

Comment: @RiversMcForge I was suspicious that was my error. Thank you so much, I would appreciate that.

Comment: The right move to make on $\Bbb{E}[XZ]$ here, for the record, is a bit counter-intuitive, as you start by making the expression look messier: by law of total expectation, $$\Bbb{E}[XZ] = \Bbb{E}[\Bbb{E}[XZ| Y]].$$ Adding the extra expectation inside is what gives you the room to maneuver $Z$ out of the (innermost) expectation and then simplify: $$\Bbb{E}[\Bbb{E}[XZ| Y]] = \Bbb{E}[Z \Bbb{E}[X|Y]],$$ which by definition of $Z$ is just $\Bbb{E}[Z^2]$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge This cleared up my proof for me. Thank you!